# Add N to Title in Pie Chart

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a code that outputs a pie chart as such:

```
AGE_COUNTS=PIE_DATA.Age_Group.value_counts()
ax = AGE_COUNTS.plot(kind='pie', autopct='%.0f%%', shadow = True, label="")
ax.set_title("LWBS Age Distribution")
```

[image]

I would like to add the N of the total counts by age to the title so for example the title would read `'LWBS Age Distribution (n=14)'`. So for example, if I add up all of the counts for each age group the total population would equal 14. I want to do this automated so I don't have to manually change the title every time I update the date range for the data. I haven't been able to find much literature online that speaks to my request.

Comment: There is an issue with the "" starting at {len...It doesnt cover the whole string as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the title with an f-string:

```
ax.set_title(f"LWBS Age Distribution (n={len(PIE_DATA)})")
```